# shp2pgsql dumping double fields with comma separator instead of dot

Tags: postgis

I guess the source shapefile is the culprit, but is there any way to change to fix it through shp2pgsql?

Obviously Postgres throw an error with:
INSERT INTO "public"."a" ("area","perimeter", ...) VALUES ('5282,98830007762','313,033597376014', ...);

EDIT:
I'm not entirely sure, but I think this is solved if you connect putty from a computer with an English OS

Comment: One way to deal with this is to pipe it through something like sed between shp2pgsql and psql, doing a regex replace on the commas. There is a format switch, but I think this is just for the text encoding, not the decimal separator.  `pgsql2shp filename schema.tblname | sed -s 's/comma_regex/period_pattern/g' | psql dbname`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a locale that formats floating points with a comma. Try setting the environment variable `LC_NUMERIC=C`. E.g.:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=C shp2pgsql myshp.shp > myshp.sql
```

Comment: Didn't change the result, still comma as separator

Comment: @jpp1jpp1 you might have stumbled across a bug, if you want to describe it in a [new ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/report) (requires creating a login) you can help the developers fix it. You would need to describe more details, such as your version of PostGIS, OS info, and locale settings.

Comment: Thx, could you post the issue yourself? Couldn't find at first sight any signup link. I can complete here all the additional details you might need

Comment: @jpp1jpp1 you can get a sign-in [from this page](http://www.osgeo.org/osgeo_userid) which will work on the 'new ticket' link above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by:

```
export LANG=en.UTF8 
shp2pgsql myshp.shp > myshp.sql
```

Comment: Just tried and it still outputs ",". Somehow locale seems to be tied to the source shp file. I'm using postgis 2.0.6